# How to access active directory by multiple user in MS Azure

Tags: azure

I have an active directory in MS Azure. I want my colleague to use the same directory so that we can do some RND on the same. I have already created user for them using their hotmail id. I have also changed the user role to "Global Admin" for them. They cant see any option to access the same active directory after log in. Is there any way they will give the url like

https://manage.windowsazure.com/@IamNewInAzurehotmail.onmicrosoft.com#Workspaces/All/dashboard
and log in with their hotmail account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add him in Administrators List in setting option of Azure Panel.

Steps:

1. Login to Azure Portal with Root administrator.
2. Go to left panel and select Setting.
3. Go to Administrators tab in right side pane.
4. Click on Add button in task pane and add his hotmail or Organisation ID for Co- Administrator, Select the subscription in which you want to allow him.
5. Click on tick mark to apply these settings.